# Modify config files with sed in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I am trying to set `net.ipv4.ip_forward` to 1 in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.The following works fine but it sure missing some edge cases

```
#Enable IP packet forwarding so that our VPN traffic can pass through.
sed -i 's/net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0/net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1/g' /etc/sysctl.conf 
sed -i 's/#net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1/net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1/g' /etc/sysctl.conf 
grep -qF "net.ipv4.ip_forward" /etc/sysctl.conf  || echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

For e.g if the sysctl.conf contain any one of the following it won't match

`#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

`##net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`.

Is there a more reliable way to modify settings in config files ?

Comment: Yes, by specifying that `net.ipv4.ip_forward` should be at the very beginning of the line. Simple as that. Can be found in any sed tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `-r` switch to enable Extended Regular Expressions(`ERE`) in `GNU sed` and optionally match the white-space and the `#` occurence with the [regex `?` optional item anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html),

```
sed -ir 's/#{1,}?net.ipv4.ip_forward ?= ?(0|1)/net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1/g' /etc/sysctl.conf
```

This will match for any of the below input lines and modify it with the replacement part `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
##net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
##net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
#net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
##net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

See the [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RatBHa/1) for more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

What about removing all lines matching `net.ipv4.ip_forward`, no matter whether commented out or not and then appending what you need?

```
fgrep -v net.ipv4.ip_forward /etc/sysctl.conf > /etc/sysctl.conf.tmp
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf.tmp
mv /etc/sysctl.conf.tmp /etc/sysctl.conf
```

This is simple and readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this setting to do it for zero or more spaces and zero or multiple #(comment)

```
sed -i 's/[#| ]*net.ipv4.ip_forward[ ]*=[ ]*0/net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1/g' /etc/sysctl.conf 
grep -qF "net.ipv4.ip_forward" /etc/sysctl.conf  || echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Comment: While this is a good attempt, but still won't work for inputs `#net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` and `##net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

Comment: Try this sed -i 's/[#| ]*net.ipv4.ip_forward[ ]*=[ |0|1]*/net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1/g' /etc/sysctl.conf